# Create a DOS bootable USB drive (16 GB)

Tags: boot, iso, unetbootin, usb-creator, ms-dos

I have two computers, both on Ubuntu, and I need to upgrade the BIOS on one of them. I can get a version of [DOS](http://www.allbootdisks.com/download/iso.html) and also use [UNetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) with FreeDOS, but I can't copy the BIOS firmware and flash utility to the key because

1. The USB device is 16GB, thus cannot seem be read from DOS
2. The DOS/FreeDOS images don't have enough free space to copy the files

I *could* try and use a CD to burn the BIOS files, unfortunately I don't have any at hand at the moment (and would need to be a CDR-W as it seems a waste to burn 2.2MB on a 640MB device... to be discarded after, too!)

That being said, I have tried...

- ...to repartition the USB device, with no luck.
- ...using `dd` to copy the ISO (and even an IMG) over the USB device
- ...directly accessing the USB device from DOS/FreeDOS

No success.

Is it even possible? With USB devices being bigger and bigger, finding a DOS-compatible one seems like a futile initiative, no? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Download this file I've made for you:

```
wget http://artinvoice.hu/FreeDOS-1.1-memstick-2-256M.img
```

After that take a pendrive bigger or equal to 256Mb, and use `dd` to transfer the image to the pendrive. Be careful, it will destroy all your data on the pendrive, afterwards you have to repartiton it!

The command is:

```
dd if=FreeDOS-1.1-memstick-2-256M.img of=/dev/sdb
```

if the pendrive is under /dev/sdb, if not, adjust the command to fit your system.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this file. How did you create it?

Comment: Well, it works! Now, if you can provide how you created the `img` file, this will be it.

Comment: I'm glad that works. Hmm... It doesn't deserve at least an upvote? :)